# Discord.py Bot sending file to Discord Channel

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make my discord bot send a jpg file to my discord server, but I keep getting an error that seems pretty uncommon as I can not find any solutions to it on the internet...

the error is...
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientRequestError: Can not write request body for https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/454374995758678029/messages

My imports are

```
import time

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
```

The code that I will pull out that the error is related to is

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)

async def image(ctx):

        await bot.send_file(ctx.message.channel, open('halogen.jpg'))
```

Am I just missing an import or is there an actual problem with my code?

Thanks guys

Comment: Sidenote: passing `open(...)` to a function is usually a bad idea, since that image might never get closed, so if this command is run multiple times, you could leak file handles and eventually crash your bot.

Comment: Josh, you were right... I got rid of open and my code instantly worked... always the small things

Comment: You should be opening your object in `'rb'` mode.  You can also just pass the path to the file instead of a file object.  See the [`send_file` documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.send_file)

Answer (score 14):

I was researching the same thing and I found this to work:

```py
await ctx.send(file=discord.File(r'c:\location\of\the_file_to\send.png'))
```

Here is where I found it: [link](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/send+image+discord.py)

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it this way.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def send(ctx):
    area=ctx.message.channel
    await bot.send_file(area, r"c:\location\of\the_file_to\send.png",filename="Hello",content="Message test")
```

You can refer to the discord documentation for it here [link](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.send_file)

Answer (score 2):

You can send it without ctx:

```
async def timer():

    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(number_of_channel)
    while True:
        await channel.send('Working!', file=discord.File("file.txt"))
        await asyncio.sleep(10)#seconds
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from discord import File

@bot.command(name="photo")
async def img(ctx):
    file_name = "image.jpg" # if in folder of bot.py, else write path before
    await ctx.send(file=File(file_name))
```

I belive 100% of successfully