# How can I get my discord bot to send mp3 files? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I want my discord bot to send mp3 files that I have on my pc when I do a certain command.
Let's say the command is -hello
When I say -hello I want the bot to send an mp3 file on my pc with the name "hello"

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer here: [Discord.py Bot sending file to Discord Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50860397/13008170)
If you want to attach the file with your message, then do this with

```
await ctx.send(file=discord.File(r'c:\location\of\the_file_to\send.mp3'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the whole "code" using what gXLg send

```py
from discord.ext import commands
    
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')
    
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
await ctx.send(file=discord.File(r'location\to\file\hello.mp3'))

client.run('your token here')
```